# UPDATE query with UNION

Tags: oracle, sql-update, union

This query works on Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1 SET t1.FIELD4=(
    SELECT SUM(t4.FIELD4)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t2.FIELD1, t2.FIELD2, t2.FIELD4
        FROM TABLE1 t2
        UNION
        SELECT t3.FIELD1, t3.FIELD2, t3.FIELD4
        FROM TABLE2 t3
    ) t4
    WHERE t4.FIELD1=t1.FIELD1 AND t4.FIELD2=t1.FIELD2
)
```

But I would like to move WHERE clause in SELECT subqueries like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1 SET t1.FIELD4=(
    SELECT SUM(FIELD4)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t2.FIELD1, t2.FIELD2, t2.FIELD4
        FROM TABLE1 t2
        WHERE t2.FIELD1=t1.FIELD1 AND t2.FIELD2=t1.FIELD2
        UNION
        SELECT t3.FIELD1, t3.FIELD2, t3.FIELD4
        FROM TABLE2 t3
        WHERE t3.FIELD1=t1.FIELD1 AND t3.FIELD2=t1.FIELD2
    )
)
```

But I have this error:

> ORA-00904: "T1"."FIELD2" : invalid identifier

Why I can't use t1 fields in subqueries?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see how that query works at all. Looks like it would throw an exception in any version of Oracle, since the inline view aliased as `t4` doesn't return columns named `FIELD1` or `FIELD2`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233910/is-there-a-nesting-limit-for-correlated-subqueries-in-oracle

Comment: @spencer7593: you're right!!! I edit my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason Oracle is returning the error is that you can't reference columns from the outer query more than one level deep inside a correlated subquery.

(That same question is answered in other questions on StackOverflow.)

**UPDATE**

The approach I illustrated earlier (below) will only work if we can get an inline view where t1 is key preserved. (Entirely my bad. That approach does work in MySQL. I've been working with MySQL for long enough that I'm expecting Oracle will accept the same syntax.)

It wasn't specified that the `(fi,fo)` tuple in `t1` is a unique key. So, a correlated subquery is the way to go.

If preserving NULL values is not a requirement, then you could replace NULL values with a zero...

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1 
   SET t1.fum = NVL( SELECT SUM(t2.fum)
                       FROM TABLE1 t2
                      WHERE t2.fi = t1.fi
                        AND t2.fo = t1.fo
                   ,0)
              + NVL( SELECT SUM(t3.fum)
                       FROM TABLE2 t3
                      WHERE t3.fi = t1.fi 
                        AND t3.fo = t1.fo
                   ,0)
```

**NOTE:** This returns a zero in place of NULL; it does not preserve NULL values. (If t1.fum is defined as NOT NULL, then this wouldn't be a problem. But it's a problem in the more general case, where `t1.fum` contains NULL in all rows, and TABLE2 is empty... this would replace NULL with zero.

Additionally, if t1.fum is NOT NULL, and the the tuple `(fi,fo)` is a unique key in TABLE1, then we could avoid the need to do a SELECT to get the SUM of the values stored in t1.fum, and we'd already have that, so we could...

```
 ... SET t1.fum = t1.fum + NVL(( correlated subquery ),0)
```

But in the more general case, where we want to preserve NULL in t1.fum, I don't yet have a good way to reference t1 in the correlated subqueries without repeating the subqueries (ugghh)... I don't know of a builtin operator or function that preserves NULL like the SUM aggregate does, so that we could presere NULL when we add the numeric results of the two SUM subqueries.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

(The use case for this requirement seems a bit odd; note that UNION will eliminate duplicate rows, where UNION ALL does not.)

The original answer specified multi-table syntax that does NOT work in Oracle. This approach works with SELECT statements, but not with UPDATE statements.

<strike>Personally, I wouldn't use correlated subquery to do an operation like this; I would prefer to use a JOIN operation to get an equivalent result. For example:</strike>

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(DISTINCT r.fum) AS sum_fum, r.fi, r.fo
           FROM ( SELECT t2.fum
                       , t2.fi
                       , t2.fo
                    FROM TABLE1 t2
                   UNION
                  SELECT t3.fum
                       , t3.fi
                       , t3.fo
                    FROM TABLE2 t3
                ) r
          GROUP BY r.fi, r.fo
       ) s
    ON s.fi = t1.fi
   AND s.fo = t1.fo
   SET t1.fum = s.sum_fum
```

(If the intent is to update only a subset of rows in t1, rather than all rows in t1, I would omit the `LEFT` keyword to make it an inner join.)

**But BEFORE** I ran an update like this, I would verify first using a `SELECT` statement, such as:

```
SELECT t1.fi
     , t1.fo
     , t1.fum    AS old_fum
     , s.sum_fum AS new_fum
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(DISTINCT r.fum) AS sum_fum, r.fi, r.fo
           FROM ( SELECT t2.fum
                       , t2.fi
                       , t2.fo
                    FROM TABLE1 t2
                   UNION
                  SELECT t3.fum
                       , t3.fi
                       , t3.fo
                    FROM TABLE2 t3
                ) r
          GROUP BY r.fi, r.fo
       ) s
    ON s.fi = t1.fi
   AND s.fo = t1.fo
```

Once I had confirmed that the SELECT was working the way I wanted it to, and the values returned in the `new_fum` column were the values I wanted to assign to the `fum` column in `t1` (to replace the existing `old_fum` value), only then would I convert it to an UPDATE statement.

To make it into an UPDATE statement, I would just replace the "SELECT <list>" with the "UPDATE" keyword, and just add a "SET t1.fum = s.sum_fum" assignment to the end of the statement (or before the WHERE clause if the query had a WHERE clause).

NOTES: I made the following replacements to improve readability:

```
FIELD1 => fi
FIELD2 => fo
FIELD4 => fum
```

It's a bit odd that the inline view in the original query uses a `UNION` operator  rather than a `UNION ALL`. Because the `UNION` operator would remove any duplicate values of `FIELD4` before the values get added together... to get an equivalent result, I included the `DISTINCT` keyword inside the `SUM` aggregate.

(Obviously, if the original query had a `UNION ALL` operator, then we'd omit the `DISTINCT` keyword inside the `SUM` aggregate.)

I don't see how the original query "works" in Oracle 9; it makes references to `t4.FIELD1` but the inline view `t4` doesn't return a column named `FIELD1`.

Comment: Yes I have to use UNION ALL, and thanks for your answer, it helps me A LOT but the update query returns ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Comment: @user1334149: Entirely my bad. I've been working with MySQL so long, I forgot the limitations of Oracle syntax. That JOIN approach I illustrated will only work if we turn the SELECT statement into an inline view, and t1 is "key preserved". I will update my answer with the correlated subquery. Again, my bad.