# oracle not a group by function with nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

I do not understand why this query does not work.

Original query working on 3x servers.

```
SELECT (
        SELECT to_char(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, TEXT, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GetClobVal(), ',')) CM_LINES
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT to_char(cmline) TEXT
            FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data
            WHERE comms_matrix_id = :pkid
                AND src_net = t1.SRC_NET
                AND dst_net = t1.DST_NET
            ORDER BY cmline
            )
        ) CM_LINES
    ,t1.SRC_NET
    ,t1.DST_NET
    ,t1.SRC_NETZONE
    ,t1.DST_NETZONE
    ,t1.RPA
    ,t1.RPN
FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data t1
WHERE (t1.COMMS_MATRIX_ID = :pkid)
    AND (LOWER(t1.STATUS) LIKE '%implement%')
GROUP BY t1.SRC_NET
    ,t1.DST_NET
    ,t1.SRC_NETZONE
    ,t1.DST_NETZONE
    ,t1.RPA
    ,t1.RPN
```

On dev server this errors with `ORA-00904: "T1"."DST_NET": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

on my dev server it does not work so I decided to rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT CM_LINES.CM_LINES
    ,t1.SRC_NET
    ,t1.DST_NET
    ,t1.SRC_NETZONE
    ,t1.DST_NETZONE
    ,t1.RPA
    ,t1.RPN
FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data t1,
(
        SELECT to_char(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, TEXT, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GetClobVal(), ',')) CM_LINES, src_net, dst_net
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT to_char(cmline) TEXT, src_net, dst_net
            FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data
            WHERE comms_matrix_id = :pkid

            ORDER BY cmline
            )
        ) CM_LINES
WHERE (t1.COMMS_MATRIX_ID = :pkid)
    AND (LOWER(t1.STATUS) LIKE '%implement%')
    AND CM_LINES.src_net = t1.SRC_NET
    AND CM_LINES.dst_net = t1.DST_NET
GROUP BY CM_LINES.CM_LINES
    ,t1.SRC_NET
    ,t1.DST_NET
    ,t1.SRC_NETZONE
    ,t1.DST_NETZONE
    ,t1.RPA
    ,t1.RPN;
```

on dev server this errors with  `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"`

@Gordon

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT x.CM_LINES
    ,t1.SRC_NET
    ,t1.DST_NET
    ,t1.SRC_NETZONE
    ,t1.DST_NETZONE
    ,t1.RPA
    ,t1.RPN
FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data t1
JOIN (
    SELECT to_char(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, cml.TEXT, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GetClobVal(), ',')) CM_LINES
        ,src_net
        ,dst_net
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT to_char(cmline) TEXT
            ,src_net
            ,dst_net
        FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data
        WHERE comms_matrix_id = :pkid
        ORDER BY cmline
        ) cml ON cml.src_net = t1.SRC_NET /* sql developer reports problem here*/
        AND cml.dst_net = t1.DST_NET
    WHERE t1.COMMS_MATRIX_ID = :pkid
        AND LOWER(t1.STATUS) LIKE '%implement%'
    GROUP BY src_net
        ,dst_net
    ) x
GROUP BY x.CM_LINES
    ,t1.SRC_NET
    ,t1.DST_NET
    ,t1.SRC_NETZONE
    ,t1.DST_NETZONE
    ,t1.RPA
    ,t1.RPN;
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I Try the following i get error on group by `ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"`

```
SELECT x.CM_LINES
    ,t1.SRC_NET
    ,t1.DST_NET
    ,t1.SRC_NETZONE
    ,t1.DST_NETZONE
    ,t1.RPA
    ,t1.RPN
FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data t1
JOIN (
    SELECT to_char(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, cml.TEXT, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GetClobVal(), ',')) CM_LINES
        ,src_net
        ,dst_net
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT to_char(cmline) TEXT
            ,src_net
            ,dst_net
        FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data
        WHERE comms_matrix_id = :pkid
        ORDER BY cmline
        ) cml 
    join cml ON cml.src_net = t1.SRC_NET
        AND cml.dst_net = t1.DST_NET
    WHERE t1.COMMS_MATRIX_ID = :pkid
        AND LOWER(t1.STATUS) LIKE '%implement%'
    GROUP BY src_net
        ,dst_net
    ) x /* should there not be an on clause here? */
GROUP BY x.CM_LINES /* error here */
    ,t1.SRC_NET
    ,t1.DST_NET
    ,t1.SRC_NETZONE
    ,t1.DST_NETZONE
    ,t1.RPA
    ,t1.RPN;
```

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve? Your original problem is because the reference to ` T1.DST_NET`  is nested too deeply. [See this SO post for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1233910/146325)

Comment: You have a query that runs perfectly well on three servers but not on Dev.  Why rewrite the query just for Dev?  Rather than spend all that effort I would just try to work out why you're getting the invalid identifier exception.  My guess is that in Dev the table exists in a different schema

Comment: @ChristianPalmer the table is in the same schema

Comment: @APC if there is a nesting limit how can i remove this from DEV env?

Comment: Then see comment from @APC - your reference to T1 is nested too deeply (although I don't understand how it works on other servers)

Comment: Your outer group by should really be a distinct, since you're not actually aggregating anything (apart from the XMLAGG in the scalar subquery, which is what does need the group by as mentioned in Gordon's answer)

Comment: so on dev it is 11g and the rest run on 12g. does that mean 11g does not support query nested like that?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` in the subquery:

```
SELECT CM_LINES, t1.SRC_NET, t1.DST_NET,
       t1.SRC_NETZONE, t1.DST_NETZONE, t1.RPA, t1.RPN
FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data t1 JOIN
     (SELECT to_char(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, TEXT, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GetClobVal(), ',')) as CM_LINES,
             src_net, dst_net
      FROM (SELECT to_char(cmline) as TEXT, src_net, dst_net,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY src_net, dst_net ORDER BY cmline DESC) as seqnum
            FROM CCP.comms_matrix_data
            WHERE comms_matrix_id = :pkid
           ) CM_LINES
           ON CM_LINES.src_net = t1.SRC_NET AND
               CM_LINES.dst_net = t1.DST_NET AND
               seqnum = 1
      WHERE t1.COMMS_MATRIX_ID = :pkid AND
            LOWER(t1.STATUS) LIKE '%implement%'
      GROUP BY src_net, dst_net
     ) x
GROUP BY CM_LINES, t1.SRC_NET, t1.DST_NET
         t1.SRC_NETZONE, t1.DST_NETZONE, t1.RPA, t1.RPN;
```

`XMLAGG()` is an aggregation function.

Comment: I get an error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"` this is on `CM_LINES ON CM_LINES.src_net = t1.SRC_NET`

Comment: @shorif2000 . . . There was a mistake in the aliases, but I don't see unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: i pasted your sql in update with correct aliases. still same error