# Correlated subquery with join in oracle 11.2 select clause doesn't works

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, correlated-subquery

The following correlated subquery works very well in 12c but fails with mentioned error in 11.2. Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

**Using 11.2.0.4**

```
SQL> column member1 format A35
column member2 format A35
select a.group#, a.SEQUENCE#, a.ARCHIVED, a.STATUS,
(SELECT Member from (SELECT Member, ROWNUM AS RN FROM v$logfile b where b.group#=a.group#) WHERE RN = 1) as Member1,
(SELECT Member from (SELECT Member, ROWNUM AS RN FROM v$logfile b where b.group#=a.group#) WHERE RN = 2) as Member2,
(a.BYTES/1024/1024)
from v$log a;SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5  
(SELECT Member from (SELECT Member, ROWNUM AS RN FROM v$logfile b where b.group#=a.group#) WHERE RN = 1) as Member1,
                                                                                 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "A"."GROUP#": invalid identifier
```

**Using 12c**

```
GROUP# SEQUENCE#  ARC STATUS   MEMBER1                        MEMBER2                        (A.BYTES/1024/1024)
------ ---------- --- -------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------
 7     4901       YES INACTIVE /u02/oradata/PROD/redo06.log   /u02/oradata/PROD/redo07.log                   810
 9     4902       YES INACTIVE /u02/oradata/PROD/redo9.log    /u03/oradata/PROD/redo9.log                    808
10     4903       NO  CURRENT  /u02/oradata/PROD/redo10.log   /u03/oradata/PROD/redo10.log                   808
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a nesting limit for correlated subqueries in some versions of Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233910/is-there-a-nesting-limit-for-correlated-subqueries-in-some-versions-of-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone please correct me if I am wrong, but without ORDER BY clauses in you sub-selects, you are not guaranteed to get different members.

I believe this SQL will get you the desired results. I have tested it on Oracle 11.

```
WITH
    aset
    AS
        (SELECT MEMBER
              , group#
              , ROW_NUMBER ()
                    OVER (
                        PARTITION BY group# ORDER BY MEMBER
                    )
                    rn
           FROM v$logfile)
SELECT a.group#
     , a.sequence#
     , a.archived
     , a.status
     , member1
     , member2
  FROM v$log a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MEMBER AS member1, group#
                          FROM aset
                         WHERE rn = 1) aset1
           ON a.group# = aset1.group#
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MEMBER AS member2, group#
                          FROM aset
                         WHERE rn = 2) aset2
           ON a.group# = aset2.group#;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brian, The above query works both on 11g and 12c and solved my problem.