# query works on oracle 12c but does not work on 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have simple (but not so smart) code in sql (oracle).
This SQL works correct on oracle version 12c but have exception on oracle v. 11g. Can You give mi answere why?

```
    create table app_status (id_status int, description varchar2(20 char), range_char char(1));
    /
    create table app (id_app int,  description varchar2(20 char), range_char char(1));
    /
    insert into app_status (id_status, description,range_char) values (1,'opis 1','a');
    insert into app_status (id_status, description,range_char) values (2, 'opis 2','b');
    insert into app_status (id_status, description,range_char) values (3, 'opis 3','a');
    insert into app_status (id_status, description,range_char) values (4, 'opis 4','a');
    /
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (1,'app 1','a');
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (2,'app 2','a');
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (3,'app 3','a');
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (4,'app 4','b');
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (5,'app 5','a');
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (6,'app 6','a');
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (7,'app 7','c');
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (8,'app 8','a');
    insert into app (id_app,description,range_char) values (9,'app 9','a');
    /


    -- this query does not work on oracle v.11g
    select * from app where not exists (
           select id_status from (
                  select id_STATUS FROM APP_STATUS 
                  WHERE APP_STATUS.RANGE_CHAR = APP.RANGE_CHAR 
                  ORDER BY ID_STATUS DESC 
           ) WHERE ROWNUM=1);
```

I cnot found information in specification of oracle 11g, why does it not work. Maybe it is not correct on 12c to, but higher version tolerate irregularity?

Comment: What is the exception in Oracle 11g?

Comment: select * from app where not exists (select id_status from (select id_STATUS FROM APP_STATUS WHERE APP_STATUS.RANGE_CHAR = APP.RANGE_CHAR ORDER BY ID_STATUS DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM=1)
Error at Command Line : 23 Column : 123
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "APP"."RANGE_CHAR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

I can reproduce your exception on 11g:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM app
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                   SELECT id_status 
                     FROM (
                           SELECT id_status 
                             FROM app_status 
                            WHERE app_status.range_char = app.range_char 
                            ORDER BY id_status DESC
                           ) 
                     WHERE ROWNUM=1
                   );
Version 11.2.0.2 ORA-00904: "APP"."RANGE_CHAR": invalid identifier
Version 12.2.0.1 OK
```

I agree with @krokodilko, the query can and should be simplified, for instance to

```
SELECT * 
  FROM app 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM app_status 
                    WHERE app_status.range_char = app.range_char 
                   );
```

which then runs in 11.2 and 12.2, I am still puzzled why this is regared as an error in 11.2.

Does anybody know details?

Comment: 12c removed some limitations around nesting correlated subqueries. I couldn't find it in the documentation though. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1233910/230471

Comment: Thank You!  i founded different in documentation thanks to you.  <br>https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries007.htm#SQLRF52340   https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Using-Subqueries.html#GUID-53A705B6-0358-4E2B-92ED-A83DE83DFD20. It's an honor for me to learn from you.

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out one subquery and remove ORDER BY:

```
 select * from app where not exists (
  --         select id_status from (
                  select id_STATUS FROM APP_STATUS 
                  WHERE APP_STATUS.RANGE_CHAR = APP.RANGE_CHAR 
  --                ORDER BY ID_STATUS DESC 
 --          ) WHERE ROWNUM=1
 );
```

or simply remove them:

```
     select * from app where not exists (
                      select id_STATUS FROM APP_STATUS 
                      WHERE APP_STATUS.RANGE_CHAR = APP.RANGE_CHAR 
     );
```

this subquery it is unnecessary in `NOT EXISTS` operator, this operator checks wheter any row exists or not, there is no need to filter out only 1 record nor order a resutset.
By the way, if you remove this subquery and ORDER BY, then the whole query will probably be faster while giving exactly the same results.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is no my query I just want to migrate application on oracle v.11g without modificate sourcecode (which generate query by hibernate).

Comment: Well, show your hibernate code and entity mappings. Unfortunately, you will not be able to migrate from Oracle 12c to 11g without changing the source code, this is not possible.