# Left outer join invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I can't seem to get these left outer joins right using derived tables.  I need to do it this way as I need to use a subquery in the qualification.

The error I am receiving is `ORA-00904: "E"."ENCNTR_ID": invalid identifier`

I've tried moving the position of the join around and reversing the columns around the =.  There's plenty of posts out there related to this but none of them have provided me the answer.  Many are in regards to having multiple tables comma delimited in the FROM clause but my query doesn't have that.

```
SELECT
    E.ENCNTR_ID
    ,E.REASON_FOR_VISIT
    -- ,D.DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY AS DISCHARGE_DX
    -- ,D.DIAG_FTDESC AS WORKING_DX
    ,cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(E.REG_DT_TM, 2, 126) as reg_dt_tm
    ,cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(E.DISCH_DT_TM, 2, 126) as disch_dt_tm
    ,FACILITY.DISPLAY AS FACILITY
    ,P.PERSON_ID
    ,P.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED
    ,cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(P.BIRTH_DT_TM, 2, P.BIRTH_TZ) as birth_dt_tm
    ,MRN.ALIAS AS MRN
    ,FIN.ALIAS AS FIN
    ,ENC_TYPE.DISPLAY AS ENCOUNTER_TYPE
    ,NURSE_UNIT.DISPLAY AS NURSE_UNIT
    ,ROOM.DISPLAY AS ROOM
    ,BED.DISPLAY AS BED
    ,ADMITDOC_NAME.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED AS ADMITDOC_NAME
    ,DCDOC_NAME.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED AS DCDOC_NAME
    ,ADMIT_SRC.DISPLAY AS ADMIT_SOURCE
    ,ADMIT_TYPE.DISPLAY AS ADMIT_TYPE
    ,ESDP.RESULT_VAL AS ESDP
    ,DISCH_DISPOSITION.DISPLAY AS DISCH_DISPOSITION
FROM ENCOUNTER E
-- JOIN DISCHARGE D ON (D.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
--  AND D.ACTIVE_IND = 1
--  AND D.END_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM > SYSDATE
JOIN PERSON P ON (P.PERSON_ID = E.PERSON_ID)
JOIN CODE_VALUE ENC_TYPE ON (ENC_TYPE.CODE_VALUE = E.ENCNTR_TYPE_CLASS_CD)
JOIN ENCNTR_ALIAS FIN ON (FIN.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
    AND FIN.ENCNTR_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = 1077 -- FIN CODE
    AND FIN.ACTIVE_IND = 1
    AND FIN.ACTIVE_STATUS_CD = 188
JOIN ENCNTR_ALIAS MRN ON (MRN.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
    AND MRN.ENCNTR_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = 1079 -- MRN CODE
    AND MRN.ACTIVE_IND = 1
    AND MRN.ACTIVE_STATUS_CD = 188
JOIN CODE_VALUE FACILITY on (FACILITY.CODE_VALUE = E.LOC_FACILITY_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE NURSE_UNIT on (NURSE_UNIT.CODE_VALUE = E.LOC_NURSE_UNIT_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE ROOM on (ROOM.CODE_VALUE = E.LOC_ROOM_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE BED on (BED.CODE_VALUE = E.LOC_BED_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE DISCH_DISPOSITION on (DISCH_DISPOSITION.CODE_VALUE = E.DISCH_DISPOSITION_CD)
JOIN PRSNL ADMITDOC_NAME ON (ADMITDOC_NAME.PERSON_ID = OA.ORDER_PROVIDER_ID)
LEFT JOIN CLINICAL_EVENT HOSP_SUM ON (HOSP_SUM.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
    AND HOSP_SUM.EVENT_CD = :p17
    AND HOSP_SUM.RESULT_STATUS_CD IN (:p19, :p20, :p21)
    AND HOSP_SUM.RECORD_STATUS_CD = 188 -- ACTIVE
    AND HOSP_SUM.VALID_UNTIL_DT_TM > cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(SYSDATE, 1, 126)
LEFT JOIN PRSNL DCDOC_NAME ON (DCDOC_NAME.PERSON_ID = HOSP_SUM.VERIFIED_PRSNL_ID)
JOIN CODE_VALUE ADMIT_SRC ON (ADMIT_SRC.CODE_VALUE = E.ADMIT_SRC_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE ADMIT_TYPE ON (ADMIT_TYPE.CODE_VALUE = E.ADMIT_TYPE_CD)
LEFT JOIN CLINICAL_EVENT ESDP ON (ESDP.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
    AND ESDP.EVENT_CD = :p18
    AND ESDP.RESULT_STATUS_CD IN (:p19, :p20, :p21)
    AND ESDP.RECORD_STATUS_CD = 188 -- ACTIVE
    AND ESDP.VALID_UNTIL_DT_TM > cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(SYSDATE, 1, 126)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT O.* FROM ORDERS O WHERE O.ORDER_ID = (
        SELECT MAX(O2.ORDER_ID) FROM ORDERS O2 WHERE O2.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID AND O2.CATALOG_CD = :p22 AND O2.ACTIVE_IND = 1
    )) O ON
    O.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID
--        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
--            SELECT * FROM ORDER_ACTION WHERE ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND ACTION_TYPE_CD IN (:p23, :p24) AND ACTION_SEQUENCE = (
--                SELECT MAX(OA2.ACTION_SEQUENCE)
--                FROM ORDER_ACTION OA2
--                WHERE OA2.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND OA2.ACTION_TYPE_CD IN (:p23, :p24)
--            )) OA ON
--            O.ORDER_ID = OA.ORDER_ID
WHERE E.ENCNTR_ID IN (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9, :p10, :p11, :p12, :p13, :p14, :p15, :p16)
ORDER BY PERSON_ID ASC, REG_DT_TM DESC;
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to reference `E.ENCNTR_ID`, which is defined in the root query, in a subquery which is what it is complaining about.

Comment: Why are there brackets around the join predicates? Also what are filter predicates doing in the join clauses?

Comment: The brackets were there by someone besides myself.  What do you mean filter predicates in the join clauses?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. PS Clearly this is non-minimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a nesting limit for correlated subqueries in some versions of Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233910/is-there-a-nesting-limit-for-correlated-subqueries-in-some-versions-of-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

E.ENCNTR_ID on the third line below will not be found, because this subquery is outside the scope of the parent query, so you'll need to join your E table in this subquery. However, since you need the ENCTR_ID specificity in this subquery, you should consider using a CTE (WITH Clause) to prefetch this table.

```
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT O.* FROM ORDERS O WHERE O.ORDER_ID = (
            SELECT MAX(O2.ORDER_ID) FROM ORDERS O2 WHERE O2.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID AND 
    O2.CATALOG_CD = :p22 AND O2.ACTIVE_IND = 1
        )) O ON
        O.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID
```

Comment: It seems that I get farther by moving the qualifications in the subquery up to the main derived table query.  Then in my subquery I can join to O2 via `O2.ENCNTR_ID = O.ENCNTR_ID`.  But now it is complaining about the following LEFT JOIN from my derived table O to ORDER_ACTION.  I tried the same fix but I still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the main thing I was lacking was using a GROUP BY in my subquery.  I didn't need to use a derived table at all.  Just use a subquery with GROUP BY and duplicate the qualifications in the main join query and the subquery.

```sql
SELECT
    E.ENCNTR_ID
    ,E.REASON_FOR_VISIT
    -- ,D.DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY AS DISCHARGE_DX
    -- ,D.DIAG_FTDESC AS WORKING_DX
    ,cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(E.REG_DT_TM, 2, 126) as reg_dt_tm
    ,cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(E.DISCH_DT_TM, 2, 126) as disch_dt_tm
    ,FACILITY.DISPLAY AS FACILITY
    ,P.PERSON_ID
    ,P.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED
    ,cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(P.BIRTH_DT_TM, 2, P.BIRTH_TZ) as birth_dt_tm
    ,MRN.ALIAS AS MRN
    ,FIN.ALIAS AS FIN
    ,ENC_TYPE.DISPLAY AS ENCOUNTER_TYPE
    ,NURSE_UNIT.DISPLAY AS NURSE_UNIT
    ,ROOM.DISPLAY AS ROOM
    ,BED.DISPLAY AS BED
    -- ,ADMITDOC_NAME.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED AS ADMITDOC_NAME
    ,DCDOC_NAME.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED AS DCDOC_NAME
    ,ADMIT_SRC.DISPLAY AS ADMIT_SOURCE
    ,ADMIT_TYPE.DISPLAY AS ADMIT_TYPE
    ,ESDP.RESULT_VAL AS ESDP
    ,DISCH_DISPOSITION.DISPLAY AS DISCH_DISPOSITION
FROM ENCOUNTER E
-- JOIN DISCHARGE D ON (D.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
--  AND D.ACTIVE_IND = 1
--  AND D.END_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM > SYSDATE
JOIN PERSON P ON (P.PERSON_ID = E.PERSON_ID)
JOIN CODE_VALUE ENC_TYPE ON (ENC_TYPE.CODE_VALUE = E.ENCNTR_TYPE_CLASS_CD)
JOIN ENCNTR_ALIAS FIN ON (FIN.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
    AND FIN.ENCNTR_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = 1077 -- FIN CODE
    AND FIN.ACTIVE_IND = 1
    AND FIN.ACTIVE_STATUS_CD = 188
JOIN ENCNTR_ALIAS MRN ON (MRN.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
    AND MRN.ENCNTR_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = 1079 -- MRN CODE
    AND MRN.ACTIVE_IND = 1
    AND MRN.ACTIVE_STATUS_CD = 188
JOIN CODE_VALUE FACILITY on (FACILITY.CODE_VALUE = E.LOC_FACILITY_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE NURSE_UNIT on (NURSE_UNIT.CODE_VALUE = E.LOC_NURSE_UNIT_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE ROOM on (ROOM.CODE_VALUE = E.LOC_ROOM_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE BED on (BED.CODE_VALUE = E.LOC_BED_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE DISCH_DISPOSITION on (DISCH_DISPOSITION.CODE_VALUE = E.DISCH_DISPOSITION_CD)
LEFT JOIN ORDERS O ON
    O.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID AND O.CATALOG_CD = :p22 AND O.ACTIVE_IND = 1 AND O.ORDER_ID IN (
        SELECT MAX(O2.ORDER_ID) FROM ORDERS O2 WHERE O2.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID AND O2.CATALOG_CD = :p22 AND O2.ACTIVE_IND = 1 GROUP BY O2.ENCNTR_ID
    )
LEFT JOIN ORDER_ACTION OA ON
    OA.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND OA.ACTION_TYPE_CD IN (:p23, :p24) AND OA.ACTION_SEQUENCE IN (
        SELECT MAX(OA2.ACTION_SEQUENCE) FROM ORDER_ACTION OA2 WHERE OA2.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND OA2.ACTION_TYPE_CD IN (:p23, :p24) GROUP BY OA2.ORDER_ID
    )
LEFT JOIN PRSNL ADMITDOC_NAME ON (ADMITDOC_NAME.PERSON_ID = OA.ORDER_PROVIDER_ID)
LEFT JOIN CLINICAL_EVENT HOSP_SUM ON (HOSP_SUM.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
    AND HOSP_SUM.EVENT_CD = :p17
    AND HOSP_SUM.RESULT_STATUS_CD IN (:p19, :p20, :p21)
    AND HOSP_SUM.RECORD_STATUS_CD = 188 -- ACTIVE
    AND HOSP_SUM.VALID_UNTIL_DT_TM > cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(SYSDATE, 1, 126)
LEFT JOIN PRSNL DCDOC_NAME ON (DCDOC_NAME.PERSON_ID = HOSP_SUM.VERIFIED_PRSNL_ID)
JOIN CODE_VALUE ADMIT_SRC ON (ADMIT_SRC.CODE_VALUE = E.ADMIT_SRC_CD)
JOIN CODE_VALUE ADMIT_TYPE ON (ADMIT_TYPE.CODE_VALUE = E.ADMIT_TYPE_CD)
LEFT JOIN CLINICAL_EVENT ESDP ON (ESDP.ENCNTR_ID = E.ENCNTR_ID)
    AND ESDP.EVENT_CD = :p18
    AND ESDP.RESULT_STATUS_CD IN (:p19, :p20, :p21)
    AND ESDP.RECORD_STATUS_CD = 188 -- ACTIVE
    AND ESDP.VALID_UNTIL_DT_TM > cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(SYSDATE, 1, 126)
WHERE E.ENCNTR_ID IN (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9, :p10, :p11, :p12, :p13, :p14, :p15, :p16)
ORDER BY PERSON_ID ASC, REG_DT_TM DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.